# Magento Product url from id in an extension

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, products, ajax, product-urls

my problem is, that i want to get a productUrl from productid (seems simple) BUT i need that productUrl in a file which is called by an ajax post.
Ill show u some files to get an overview.

My test.phtml file which contains the link u can click and the ajaxpost which is calling my php file.

```
<?php
     $product_id = Mage::registry('current_product')->getId();
     $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id); 
?>

<?php if(Mage::helper('core')->isModuleOutputEnabled('XXXXX_Productpdf')): ?>
<?php $displayFrontend = Mage::getStoreConfig('datasheet/general/dropdown'); ?>
<?php if($displayFrontend == 1): ?>
<div class="pdfdiv">
    <i id="datasheetLoading" class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i><a href="" id="createDatasheet"> <?php echo $product->getName();?> Datasheet </a><label id="generatingDatasheet">Generating Datasheet</label>
    <input id="datasheetProductId" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $product_id?>">
</div>
<script>
    jQuery("#datasheetLoading").css("display", "none");
    jQuery("#generatingDatasheet").css("display", "none");
    jQuery('#createDatasheet').click( function() { 
        var productid = jQuery("#datasheetProductId" ).val();
        var myKeyVals = {"productid" : productid};
        test = "test";
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: myKeyVals,
            url: "/app/code/local/XXXXX/Productpdf/pdf/createDatasheet.php",
             beforeSend: function(xhr){          
                jQuery("#datasheetLoading").css("display", "");
                jQuery("#createDatasheet").css("display", "none");
                jQuery("#generatingDatasheet").css("display", "");
            },
            success: function(data) {
                window.open(data,'_blank' );
                jQuery("#datasheetLoading").css("display", "none");
                jQuery("#generatingDatasheet").css("display", "none");
                jQuery("#createDatasheet").css("display", "");  
            }
        });
        return false;
    });

</script>
<?php endif ?>
<?php endif ?>
```

So as u can see this phtml contians a link which call my createDatasheet.php.
In this file i need to get the product url all i got is the product id.
createDatasheet.php:

```
<?php
    require_once("../../../../../Mage.php");    
    umask(0);
    Mage::app();
    $productid = $_POST["productid"];
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productid);
    $productName = $product->getName();
?>
```

If i echo the $productName there comes the name of my product so this part works so what i need now is:

```
$productUrl = ?
```

what i have tried:

```
    Mage::getUrl().$product->getUrlPath(); 
    Mage::getUrl().$product->getUrlPath();
    $product->getUrlInStore();
    $product->getProductUrl();
    Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')->getAttributeRawValue($productId, 'attribute_code', $storeId);
```

What it should return

```
http://magento2.dev/index.php/categoryName/productName.html
```

What it actually return

```
http://magento2.dev/createDatasheet.php/productName.html?SID=s8v4n82sotc3tv7dpot8dq6df6
```

If i call the $product->getProductUrl(); in my test.phtml file i get the url i need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just looking to get the product url to createDataSheet.php, why don't you just send it through the ajax?

```
<script>
jQuery("#datasheetLoading").css("display", "none");
jQuery("#generatingDatasheet").css("display", "none");
jQuery('#createDatasheet').click( function() { 
    var productid = jQuery("#datasheetProductId" ).val();
    var myKeyVals = {
        "productid" : productid,
        "productUrl": <?php echo $product->getProductUrl(); ?>
    };
    test = "test";
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: myKeyVals,
        url: "/app/code/local/XXXXX/Productpdf/pdf/createDatasheet.php",
         beforeSend: function(xhr){          
            jQuery("#datasheetLoading").css("display", "");
            jQuery("#createDatasheet").css("display", "none");
            jQuery("#generatingDatasheet").css("display", "");
        },
        success: function(data) {
            window.open(data,'_blank' );
            jQuery("#datasheetLoading").css("display", "none");
            jQuery("#generatingDatasheet").css("display", "none");
            jQuery("#createDatasheet").css("display", "");  
        }
    });
    return false;
});

</script>
```

Then just get it like you do with productid:

```
$productUrl = $_POST["productUrl"];
```

Answer (score 0):

`http://magento2.dev/createDatasheet.php/productName.html?SID=s8v4n82sotc3tv7dpot8dq6df6` is simply the url with session id parameter.

First I'd ensure that this is disabled in the magento back-end - [see this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/38502/how-to-remove-sid-from-url)

If that doesn't work, you can quickly strip the parameter from the URL using the following php:

`$url = strtok($url, '?');`

More information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251582/beautiful-way-to-remove-get-variables-with-php/1251650#1251650).

**EDIT**
To fix the URL as specified in your comment below, you can use a simple `str_replace`:

```
$url = strtok($url, '?');
$ur = str_replace('createDatasheet.php','index.php/CategoryName', $url);
```

Which will replace the 'createDatasheet.php' part of the url with 'index.php/CategoryName' - creating a proper URL.

Comment: With $url = strtok($url , '?');  is my result http://magento2.dev/createDatasheet.php/productName.html but it should be http://magento2.dev/index.php/CategoryName/productName.html. The createDatasheet.php is the file where i call my $product->getUrlInStore(); I need a link where the user can click and refer to the $product. And i dont have a secound store url or anything like this its just 1 domain

Comment: I see - I will update my answer to fix that.