# How to Remove SID query from Magento 2.1.2 URLs

Tags: magento-2.1.2

How to **Remove SID** query from **Magento 2.1.2** URLs

[image: How to Remove SID query from Magento 2.1.2 URLs]

I have already tried following solution but **din't work for me**

[How to remove SID (session ID) from URL in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/147373/how-to-remove-sid-session-id-from-url-in-magento-2)

[How to remove SID from URL?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/38502/how-to-remove-sid-from-url)

http://inchoo.net/dev-talk/remove-sid-from-magento-urls/

https://www.acunetix.com/vulnerabilities/web/php-session-use_trans_sid-enabled

Answer (score 0):

Go to the `Store > Configuration > General > Web > Session Validation Settings > Use SID on Storefront and set its value to No`

If this setting doesn't work for you, then you might be facing the known issue https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5517, which has been fixed in recent version. 
I didn't check it myself if it is actually fixed or not.
If you are facing this issue then follow https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/38720ea0920622b8b66e2b576ea7d630ff9294c1#diff-136fab368b46720917c2f26414a22b6a

I have used this solution as well to fix this issue in one of my Magento2.1 project.